# How do I describe a relationship like "issue has status" in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, relationships

I am developing an "issue tracker" app in Rails 3 but I am having trouble describing the relationship between an "Issue" and its "Status". Each issue can only have one status - I'd like this to be a combo box in HTML - but clearly each status can be assigned to multiple issues. I started with "issue has one status" but then I ran into problems retrieving that status in the view. I assume this is correct, but I must need something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Issue belongs_to :status` and `Status has_many :issues` instead.

When you use a `has_one` association, Rails will look for the foreign key `issue_id` in the `statuses` table. This is not what you want. You want issues to point to statuses, not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

In this case an issue belongs to a certain status:

```
class Issue
  belongs_to :status
end
```

Think of status as a type of category that each issue belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

If you won't be allowing a custom status, it makes more sense to have the all status' as a constant array (used for select) and a `status` string field in issues.  You will still be able to list all issues with a status with a scope.

#### Update for the question

```
class Issue
    STATUSES = [ "Open", "Closed" ]

    scope :with_status, lambda { |status| where(:status => [*status]) }
end
```

In view,

```
<%= f.select :status, Issue::STATUSES %>
```

You'll need a field in the database.  So in a migration:

```
add_column :issues, :status, :string
```

To find Issues with status in controller:

```
@open_issues = Issue.with_status("Open").all;
@current_issues = Issue.with_status([ "Pending", "Waiting on Review"]).all;
```

Or with an association:

```
@closed_issues = @project.issues.with_status("Closed");
```

Comment: Correct: I won't be allowing a custom status. There will be fixed values like "Open" and "Closed". How do I make such a constant array and how do I get the correct values into the views for "Issue"?